# Magento2: Cart price rule not applying

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

Bit of a strange one here I think. Using Magento 2 all I want to do is give a 10% discount on three products when a certain three products are in the cart.

I have gone to "cart price rules -> actions". If ALL of these conditions are TRUE. SKU is PRODSKU1, PRODSKU2, PRODSKU3. Then added 10% discount.

For some reason this just doesn't work. If I change "SKU IS" to "SKU IS ONE OF" it does work, but obviously that's not quite the rule I want. I want them ALL to be in the cart. Any help?

If it sheds any light, all three SKUs I am adding are from the same configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

You can make these changes directly in the `cart.phtml`

Above everything on the `cart.phtml` you can check the current customer's cart and check if all three products exist on the page.

If they do then you grab each product using

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$price = <newPriceThatyouWant>
$product->setData('price', <newPriceThatyouWant>)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
```

you have to use `$this` when defining the product or else it will update the price in general. ask any questions you want to me and i'll get to them asap

Comment: Do not do this, it will change the price permanently.